# Sharing views for different controllers

Tags: php, angularjs

Originally, I am a PHP (and consequently a Laravel) developer. When I would write for example a simple blog app, I would have these routes:

`/blog/:id -> SingleController
/blog/:id/edit -> EditController
/blog/new -> NewController`

And because of Laravel's form binding, I would use the same template for the creating and editing a blog post, like so:

```
{{ Form::model($post, array('route' => '...')) }}   
    {{ Form::label('name', 'Name') }}
    {{ Form::text('name') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Which is awesome, because Laravel would fill in the text field if it would be executed by the edit controller, and otherwise it would leave the field empty. Of course, the example above is simplified, because changes in action/route would have to be taken care of too.

But currently, I am working on an AngularJS app (first time), and I could not really find any information about the best approach to go about this. Is it advisable to adopt the same method for Angular too, or have I been doing it wrong all along?

The reason why I do it like this is because it makes it easier to change a form: you only need to apply your changes to one file/form, instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you look at Angular's [ui router module](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), or the ngRoute module, to help you structure your code as the developers of Angular intended.  UI-router can assist you with rendering / swapping subviews.  You can also define routes that map to particular states (i.e. combinations of certain views / html templates).  Each state has a route defined and can have a controller defined too.